# compare two files with long lists to get common elements and adjoining information

Tags: python, compare

I have two large files. File A looks like:

```
SNP_A-1780270 rs987435 7 78599583 - C G
SNP_A-1780271 rs345783 15 33395779 - C G
SNP_A-1780272 rs955894 1 189807684 - G T
SNP_A-1780274 rs6088791 20 33907909 - A G
SNP_A-1780277 rs11180435 12 75664046 + C T
SNP_A-1780278 rs17571465 1 218890658 - A T
SNP_A-1780283 rs17011450 4 127630276 - C T
```

... and has 950,000 lines.

File B looks like:

```
SNP_A-1780274
SNP_A-1780277
SNP_A-1780278
SNP_A-1780283
SNP_A-1780285
SNP_A-1780286
SNP_A-1780287
```

... and has 900,000 lines.

I need to find the common elements of file B in file A from column 1 and get an output file like:

```
SNP_A-1780274 rs6088791 20 33907909 - A G
SNP_A-1780277 rs11180435 12 75664046 + C T
SNP_A-1780278 rs17571465 1 218890658 - A T
SNP_A-1780283 rs17011450 4 127630276 - C T
```

How can I do it in the most efficient way in Python?

Comment: Can you put this into a database?

Comment: Do you have to use Python?

Comment: store each line of the smaller file as keys in a dict and iterate over the larger file and test if coulumn1 in dict

Comment: @Hedde i am new to programming and I tried some codes by looking at other posts, but couldnot figure out my way through it

Comment: @squiguy I wanted to do this using Python as I want to learn more of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If File A's lines are long compared to the "key" column 1, you could try this approach:

```
positions = {}
with open('fileA.txt') as fA:
    pos = 0
    for lineA in fA:
        uid = lineA.split(' ')[0] #gets SNP_A-1780270
        positions[uid] = pos
        pos += len(lineA)
with open('fileB.txt') as fB, open('fileA.txt') as fA, open('fileC.txt', 'w') as out:
    for lineB in fB:
        pos = positions[lineB.strip()]
        fA.seek(pos)
        lineA = fA.readline()
        out.write('%s\n', lineA)
```

You should check if the `pos += ...` is more reliable or `file.tell()`. I think, as bufferin is involved. `file.tell()` doesn't work, but it might be that the `pos += ...` needs readjustment as well.

This needs less memory as the dict version, but is probably slower due to the treatment of file A.

Comment: this gives me an error     out.write('%s\n', lineA)
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @jules Of course. I meant to write `out.write('%s\n' % lineA)` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I think a dict is ideal:

```
>>> sa = """SNP_A-1780270 rs987435 7 78599583 - C G
SNP_A-1780271 rs345783 15 33395779 - C G
SNP_A-1780272 rs955894 1 189807684 - G T
SNP_A-1780274 rs6088791 20 33907909 - A G
SNP_A-1780277 rs11180435 12 75664046 + C T
SNP_A-1780278 rs17571465 1 218890658 - A T
SNP_A-1780283 rs17011450 4 127630276 - C T"""
>>> dict_lines = {}
>>> for line in sa.split('\n'):
    dict_lines[line.split()[0]] = line


>>> sb = """SNP_A-1780274
SNP_A-1780277
SNP_A-1780278
SNP_A-1780283
SNP_A-1780285
SNP_A-1780286
SNP_A-1780287"""
>>> for val in sb.split('\n'):
    line = dict_lines.get(val, None)
    if line:
        print line


SNP_A-1780274 rs6088791 20 33907909 - A G
SNP_A-1780277 rs11180435 12 75664046 + C T
SNP_A-1780278 rs17571465 1 218890658 - A T
SNP_A-1780283 rs17011450 4 127630276 - C T
```

Comment: this works for small files, if you are dealing with large files using file iterators i the way. less memory usage...

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest… +1

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: thanks ! @Skrivar: you're totally true, I did not focus on performance, except on the `dict_lines.get` to cache the value. It looks like values files A and B are ordered (on the 1st column), this is something we can take into account (use a list instead of a dict - not ordered - and remove elements while looping on it).

Answer (score 0):

If you can invoke `join filea fileb > filec` from your Python code, it will give you what you are looking for.